# SQL INSERT INTO Error #1064 on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My code keeps giving me the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO tags (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Web Design')' at
>   line 2

I'm running the code on phpMyAdmin. Here is the code:

```
USE home_blog
INSERT INTO tags (`id`, `name`)
VALUES (1, 'Web Design');
```

id is an int and name is a varchar. I found similar problems, but they were all fixed by reserved word issues or missing parentheses. Unless I'm completely blind I don't those issues.

Comment: Have you tried to add a `;` after the use statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`USE` and `INSERT` are 2 different statements, like 2 queries. You need to write ";" at the very end of all statements if you want to execute them in the row.